# How can I add libdl to to a waf build?

Tags: waf, libdl

I'm trying to call the dlsym function from a [program compiled with the waf build system](https://github.com/ArduPilot/ardupilot), but am unable to link libdl using the wscript. This *SEEMS* like an extremely simple task but I've tried a million different things and have gotten nowhere.

Edit: It would be even better if there were a general way to add flags to the end of each build command. I've tried setting CXXFLAGS and other environment variables but they don't seem to change anything...

Comment: When linking, `LDLIBS` might be better than `CXXFLAGS`

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond Thanks but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to pass `use=dl` to the build command directly, waf will look in the config environment dict for "uselib variables" to tell it how to handle it.

A minimal wscript to build a simple `test.c` program with `dl` might look like this:

```py
def options(opt):
    opt.load('compiler_c')

def configure(conf):
    conf.load('compiler_c')

    # Make sure the we're able to link against dl
    conf.check(lib='dl')

    # If someone passes LIB_DL, to the build command, link against system library dl
    conf.env.LIB_DL = 'dl'

def build(bld):
    bld(source='test.c',
        target='test_program',
        features='c cprogram',

        # Waf will look in LIB_DL, LIBPATH_DL, CXXFLAGS_DL, etc. for how to handle this
        use='DL')
```

[Relevant documentation](https://waf.io/book/#_library_interaction_use)

Waf also provides a shorthand to avoid having to explicitly set `LIB_DL`:

```py
def configure(conf):
    conf.load('compiler_c')
    conf.check(lib='dl', uselib_store='DL')
```

This is somewhat documented [here](https://waf.io/book/#_configuration_helpers)

For the sake of completeness, here's the `test.c` file I used to test:

```c
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    dlopen("some/file", RTLD_LAZY);
    return 0;
}
```